# Decoding JSON in Java Android

Tags: java, android, json

Hi so I have encoded JSON from PHP and it comes out like this :

```
{"ticket":[
{"ticket":[{"a":"10.00","b":"1.00","c":"1.00","d":"abcde","f":"7"},
{"ticket":[{"a":"10.00","b":"1.00","c":"1.00","d":"abcde","f":"7"}
]}


    object      {1}
    ticket      [2]
            0       {6}
a   :   10.00
b   :   1.00
c   :   1.00
d   :   abcde
e   :   7

        1       {6}
a   :   10.00
b   :   1.00
c   :   1.00
d   :   abcde
e   :   7
```

when i open this in java the whole thing comes across as one `JSONObject` which I break into two `JSONArray`s the first contains the work `ticket` and then second contains

```
    {"ticket":[{"a":"10.00","b":"1.00","c":"1.00","d":"abcde","f":"7"},
    {"ticket":[{"a":"10.00","b":"1.00","c":"1.00","d":"abcde","f":"7"}
```

The second `JSONArray` as you expect has a length of 2 and can be broken down into the two lines above (each as a string) but is there a way i can get the data out of the string without doing stuff on it /tokenising it looking for the values of `a`,`b`,`c` ...etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GSON library which can convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 2):

Your provided JSON is flawed. It's missing the closing `]` on the second and third `ticket` key.

Also, if possible you should change the names, 3 `ticket` keys is highly confusing when you're searching for errors within the JSON object.
Based on that I am not sure how your JSON is supposed to look like.

You should use the provided [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) functions to access the values. They are easy to use and you don't need to create intermediate variables.

Assuming your JSON looks like this and is stored within a JSONObject variable called `json`:

```
{ "tickets":
  [
    { "tickets2": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, ...}] },
    { "tickets3": [{"a": 3, "b": 4, ...}] }
  ]
}
```

It would be possible to access the values like this:

```
json.getJSONArray("tickets").getJSONArray("tickets2").getInt("a");  // = 1
```

If you just want to check if the values are available, use the `isNull` function.

```
if (json.getJSONArray("tickets").getJSONArray("tickets2").isNull("a")) {
  //a is not available
}
```

Keep in mind that get* functions throw `JSONException` when the desired key is not available and `isNull` will return true for a value of `null` as well.